# Load two different geojson files in with different buttons

Tags: javascript, json, geojson

I am making an google maps map with two different polylines. One file with only one and another file with four of them. 
I made to buttons with `vm.loadDiggit('js/file/diggitOne.geojson')` and the other with `vm.loadDiggit('js/file/diggitTwo.geojson')`.

They look like this:

`<a class="btn btn green" ng-click="vm.loadDiggit('js/lib/diggitOne.geojson')"> Diggit one</a>
<a class="btn btn green" ng-click="vm.loadDiggit('js/lib/diggitTwo.geojson')">Diggit two</a>`

In my javascript file I load them with this function:

```js
vm.loadDiggit = function(filename){
  var promise = $.getJSON(filename);
    promise.then(function(data){
      cachedGeoJson = data;
      map.data.addGeoJson(cachedGeoJson);
    })
}
```

This works so far, but when I push the buttons multiple times there will come more and more layers over the other layer. So how can I switch easily between the two files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will help you clear all data before adding the new data.

```
map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
    map.data.remove(feature);
});
```

So this will be your new code:

```
vm.loadDiggit = function(filename){
  var promise = $.getJSON(filename);
    promise.then(function(data){
      cachedGeoJson = data;
      map.data.forEach(function(feature) {
        map.data.remove(feature);
      });
      map.data.addGeoJson(cachedGeoJson);
    })
}
```